# How can I add space to a right-aligned <input> element between cusror/caret and text?

Tags: html, css

I have an input and when a user enters a value like 5,1 the text and the cursor/caret are uncomfortable close ***depending on the font***:

[image: Rendered example of this happening]

Example code to play around with below. Experiment with your own fonts to find a similar one as I can't share the one in the image.

```html
<input
  type="text"
  style="text-align: right; font-family: 'SuperSecret';"
  value="5.1"
/>
```

How can I separate the two a bit? I don't want to alter the data in any way, so JS solutions/hacks like adding a whitespace character to the end of the sentence are not preferred.

---

Edit: As discussed in the comments of the accepted answer, it's actually not possible to do this with CSS.

Comment: Have you tried [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing)? I'm not sure it's exactly what you want, but seems like it could be a solution.

Comment: Probably the best way to handle this is to use an input mask. There are plenty of javascript plugins that offer this, then you can create you own custom input mask for that input. Like maybe this [one](https://imask.js.org/), look at the example for the "Number" example adding a space for the thousands - similar to what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`letter-spacing`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp)

```css
input {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  style="text-align: right; font-family: 'SuperSecret';"
  value="5.1"
/>
```

---

As described in the comments by @zgood, using `padding-right` will add some space between the last most character and the right side of the input field;

```css
input {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  style="text-align: right; font-family: 'SuperSecret';"
  value="5.1"
/>
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I will accept this unless someone comes up with a method that only affects the rightmost character (this adds whitespace around every charater making long inputs painful to read.

Comment: Great! If I understand correctly, a solution that only add some space between the `,` and `1` will be even better?

Comment: You can do one thing that onkeypress get text string and do this str.replace(/,/g, ", ");

Comment: @JoelPeltonen _"comes up with a method that only affects the rightmost character"_ in the case the value is `5,15` it would be `5,1  5`, do you really just want space between the `,` and the next character, not the rightmost character?

Comment: @zgood In the case of `5,16` I would want the visual space to be between `6` and the right edge of the input block. So on the right side of the rightmost character. I was really, really hoping for a CSS only solution, for me handling the databinding and having an extra space there is a pain in the butt.

Comment: @SidPro The above comment applies to your solution too, I am looking for a CSS solution and not alter the data.

Comment: @JoelPeltonen if you want the space between the rightmost character and the right edge of the input then why don't you just use `padding-right` on the input?

Comment: @zgood That's not what I want. I want space between the caret and the rightmost character, see the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @zgood Also by caret I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)

Comment: @JoelPeltonen oh... you cannot style the caret/cursor

Comment: @zgood an answer stating that perhaps a link to an explanation would be nice... :)